# Error 'Cannot read property forEach of undefined' while importing release pipeline to another project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to import release pipeline from another project to a new project in Azure DevOps. 
While trying to import release pipeline, I get error - 'Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined'.

[image]
The release pipeline consists of task groups which I have already imported successfully. Please help me with this error if you have come across this earlier. Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**
On firefox, the error is different on importing the release pipeline -

"i.environments is undefined"
[image]

Comment: This issue can not be reproduced. Have you tried to import other release pipeline into this project or import a realease pipeline without task group and can you get this error message again? I tried to import a release pipeline which includes task group but all work fine.

Comment: @YangShen-MSFT I haven't tried to import another release pipeline as I have access to only 1 release pipeline in the organisation. Is there any chance that it can be due to absence of deployment groups?

Comment: Before you reproduce this issue, please press F12 to open your browser's devtools, then reproduce it. When you meet this error again, in your devtools's `console` and `network` you would find some error message. Please share them, thanks!

Comment: It's 3 years later, and I'm having the same with Azure Pipelines, same "
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')" error.  
When I hit F12, there's nothing interesting (no errors) just two lines about: 
"ReleasesSignalRHub: Stopped watching release pipeline 8,5,3,1,6,4   ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-landing.es6.min.js:1 ReleasesSignalRHub: Stopped watching release pipeline 8"
Nothing else.